# Question about addressing someone as president

Tags: grammar

Do you still call someone president even if they are retired? What about if they were impeached? What about in Richard Nixon's situation where he abdicated to avoid impeachment. Do you still call them president even if they formally resign their office of presidency?

EDIT: abdicate, not acquitted.

Comment: Only the person currently holding office is referred to as *the President*. All previous holders of the office, no matter how they discharged it, are known as *former Presidents*.

Comment: You can also say ex-president.